# rails 3.0 controller mapping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

My routes.rb is a follows

```
resources :users  
match 'users/login'
```

and rake routes shows

```
users GET    /users(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
      POST   /users(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
  edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
       user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
            PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
            DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
users_login        /users/login(.:format)    {:controller=>"users", :action=>"login"}
```

but when i do

```
http://localhost:3000/users/login
```

its goes to /user/show. I can understand why its happening because on console it display

```
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"login"}
```

How can this be resolved.

Harshit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route for `show` is taking precedence, and Rails thinks that 'login' is an ID. To accomplish what you want you need to define your routes in this way:

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    get :login
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Place `match 'users/login'` above `resources :users`. When matching urls, rails will choose the first path in routes.rb that fits the url format. As it stands, it is finding that 'users/:id' matches 'users/login', hence id=login.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `routes.rb` file to match the code below. This will ensure that  `'users/login'` matches before `resources :users` routes. Changing `match` to `get` It will also match that route only when a `GET` request is made.

**routes.rb**

```
get 'users/login'
resources :users
```

**References**

- Check out section 3.7 in [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `http://localhost:3000/users/login` to point to your `login` method in `users` controller, you just need to do this in your routes.rb

```
get 'users/login' => 'users#login'
```

Also this should not need to be under `resources :users`